# How to get common.orig() in delegate of the table method?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Lets have *Table* with string field *Field*. You can overwrite *update()* method like this:

```
public void update()
{
    //check begin
    if (this.orig().Field != this.Field)
    {
        info('Changed');        
    }
    //check end

    super();
}
```

Is it possible to create delegate which will do the check? Delegates must match method parameters exactly and there aren't any here or they can use *XppPrePostArgs* but I do not see a way how to get _common _ and *common.orig()* from it.

How to get *common.orig()* in delegate of the table method? Is it possible?

I am using Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have delegates on table methods, but you can have event handlers. See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/event-handler-nodes-in-the-aot
- http://daxtechies.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-use-event-handler-in-microsoft.html

You would just put a pre-event handler on the table update method, then use `xppPrepostArgs` similarly to below:

```
public static void updatePreEventHandler(xppPrepostArgs _args)
{
    CompanyInfo         companyInfo = _args.getThis();
    // Common              common      = _args.getThis(); // Alternatively

    if (companyInfo.orig().Name != companyInfo.Name)
    {
        info('Changed');
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Setting it as a post-event handler will not work, as buffer and buffer.orig() are now identical.